# Calling Base Class Copy Constructor in Derived Class

Tags: c++

Just to preface, I did a lot of reading before posting because I know this is probably a very basic question, but I'm still missing something, so sorry in advance if I did...

I have a template derived class based upon another class:

```
  class BaseBuffer
  {
    public:
    // Constructor
    BaseBuffer() {};
    BaseBuffer(long buf_size);
    BaseBuffer(const BaseBuffer& orig);
....
  template <class T>
  class DataBuffer : public BaseBuffer
  {
....
```

I am implementing the copy constructor for `DataBuffer`. I have already written the copy constructor for `BaseBuffer` as shown above.

Now, as I understand, to call the copy of `BaseBuffer` as `DataBuffer` is being copied, I must do

```
    DataBuffer(const DataBuffer& orig) : BaseBuffer(orig)
    {
      // Initialize an array of memory given the type
      buf_ = new T[size_];
      ....
```

where `BaseBuffer(orig)` should, as another S.O. answer states, "This calls the Base copy constructor on the Base sub-object."

When I DON'T do this, then the expected bad thing happens: all the properties which belong to `BaseBuffer` do not get copied.

When I DO do this, unexpected bad thing happens: I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when the code gets to the point of calling `BaseBuffer(orig)`.

So this kinda does and doesn't make sense to me. As `DataBuffer` is inherited from `BaseBuffer`, it makes sense that I could call the `BaseBuffer` copy constructor and it would only "look" in the memory locations it knows about, and all the `DataBuffer` extra stuff "fits" around the base.

But on the other hand, it seems to make sense that strictly speaking, calling `BaseBuffer(&<DataBuffer>)` doesn't make sense because I have only defined `BaseBuffer(&<BaseBuffer>)`.

So my question has two parts,

1. Why is this "correct" `DataBuffer(const DataBuffer& orig) : BaseBuffer(orig) {...}` syntax (and if it's not, sorry)?
2. How do I prevent the EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is somewhere in the code you skipped. What is `size_`?

Comment: Either the object you're copying is already in a bad state, or the base class constructor is doing something wrong.  Without seeing the code, it's impossible to answer your question, except "yes, your syntax is correct for invoking the base class copy constructor from the derived class."

Comment: So I created a small example in wandbox but then I didn't know how to save the code so it all got lost. But it was working before it disappeared, as everyone suggested. Not really helpful. It would be difficult to extract my actual code, so I will see what is going on leading up to that call.

Answer (score 0):

Bottom line: I made a mistake.

As everyone stated, the syntax

```
DataBuffer(const DataBuffer& orig) : BaseBuffer(orig) {...}
```

is correct, and the error was elsewhere in my code. In my case, I was trying to copy the object before it had been initialized. Sorry for wasting everyone's time.